# Redirect to the prev of the prev url

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route

```
Route::get('/js/lang.js', 'LocalizationController@index')->name('assets.lang');
```

Now I send a get request to fetch the data after processing it in the controller.

```
<script src="/js/lang.js"></script>
```

The question is: 
For example i went to `/login` then i went to a `route` that redirect me to the prev url: 
`return back()`.
Now
When using `return back()` it redirect me to `/js/lang.js` which is the last get request. However i want the redirection to be to this route `/login`

Comment: @adam to pass the localization file from php to javascript.

Comment: return redirect()->back()

Comment: history.go(-2) with js

Comment: @dılosürücü  ```redirect()->back()``` the same with ```back()```

Comment: @adam Just a simple updating process, then ```return back()```

Comment: The header is set ```text/javascript``` see https://i.ibb.co/rkYzYKW/Untitled.png

Answer (score 2):

Only solution it

```
echo '<script>history.go(-2);</script>';
```

Comment: header('Location: <script language="JavaScript">window.history.go(-2)</script>');

Answer (score -1):

You may redirect user to login page via [named route redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-named-routes) helper.

For example, to generate a RedirectResponse to `login` named route, you may call:

```
//...
return redirect()->route('login');
//...
```

Comment: I don't know where he came from.